Aliens pose as women, seduce men and kill them
It is not Decoys (2004). It is much much older. Must be around 1980s or early 1990s from dressing sense and surroundings. It was on an English movie channel, so I think it was an English movie.
Aliens pose as hot women. Seduce men. And when the man is not watching, place a halo-like ring on his head which kills the man and turns him into a big piece of meat.
I saw it in TV (in India) in 2002. Explicit scenes during seduction.

Sorry, I don't :)

You're looking for the sci-fi cheapie Vampire Vixens from Venus from 1995.

Three Venusians land on Earth and transform themselves into beautiful buxom babes, then go about their task of sucking the life force out of unsuspecting males.

They place a device on the men's heads that emits a green halo which turns them into pieces of meat. Here are some clips from the film:



